# Grafana and InfluxDB Show latest value on null

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I'm learning how to use Graphana with InfluxDB. I've prepared a simple example that displays a graph with the number of letter occurrences across time. I use simple InfluxDB measurement with one tag `letter` and one field `count`. To display data I use the query:

```
SELECT mean("count") 
FROM "lettersCount" 
WHERE ("letter" =~ /^$letter$/) AND $timeFilter 
GROUP BY time($interval), "letter"
```

E.g.
[image: example graph]
But as you might see in my example some of the series are a bit shorter (letter 'p' on my example) because there was no occurrence of that letter at that moment.
I'm looking for a way to display previous value if there was no measurement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use InfluxDB [fill() option](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#group-by-time-intervals-and-fill):

```
SELECT mean("count") 
FROM "lettersCount" 
WHERE ("letter" =~ /^$letter$/) AND $timeFilter 
GROUP BY time($interval), "letter" fill(previous)
```